# What libraries are used to make this animation? (Animation on outside source)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to read up on how [i-remember-fr](http://i-remember.fr/en) made their circle on the page out of particles.  All of my attempts have not been fruitful, and I really want to learn how they made the effect!

Can anyone help figure out what libraries they're using, or help get an animation close to their effect?

**Here's what I've got so far...**

---

I tried to do it with THREE.js, but this is my first time making something with THREE.js, so it was difficult.  But I needed it for optimization - even though my version isn't even close to well optimized...

Can anyone help me get closer to their effect, and get more FPS in there?

**Here is my current code:**

[On CodePen](http://codepen.io/darrylhuffman/pen/LVxVor)

*Javascript Engine*

```
var AMOUNTX = 2000;
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var particles, particle, count = 0;
var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    container.setAttribute("id", "apparatus");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 350;
    camera.position.x = windowHalfX;
    camera.position.y = windowHalfY;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    particles = new Array();
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        program: function(context) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(0, 0, 0.08, 0, PI2, true);
            context.fill()
        }
    });
    var i = 0;
    for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
            particle = particles[i++] = new THREE.Sprite(material);

        particle.velocity = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3200) + 2500);

    particle.angle = (Math.PI * 2 / 0.2) * Math.floor((Math.random() * (windowHalfX * 2)*4) + 10);


    particle.distance = (Math.random() * 8 + 10) + (Math.random() * 8 + 10)+ (Math.random() * 8 + 10)+ (Math.random() * 8 + 10)+ (Math.random() * 10 + 12);

    particle.increase = Math.PI * 2 / 0.5;
    particle.position.z = particle.distance;
    particle.bx = Math.random() * 20 + 1;
    particle.by = Math.random() * 20 + 1;
          scene.add( particle );

    }
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)
}

function onWindowResize() {
    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
}


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    var i = 0;
    for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
            particle = particles[i++];
            particle.position.x = particle.bx + particle.distance * Math.cos(particle.angle / particle.velocity) + windowHalfX;
        particle.position.y = particle.by + particle.distance * Math.sin(particle.angle / particle.velocity) + windowHalfY;
          particle.angle += particle.increase;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    count += 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging around in their code, you can find a list of postprocessing effects they used, which I'm sure account for the fading in and out. Search for `amd/postprocessing/EffectComposer`.

Here's all of them: EffectComposer, SavePass, MaskPass, RenderPass, ShaderPass, CopyShader, BlendShader, HorizontalTiltShiftShader, RGBShiftShader, VerticalTiltShiftShader.

Sounds like good next reading would be on EffectComposer and its various effects.

You could, for example, use multiple layers of particles, and use MaskPasses to mask out parts of them. It looks like they do at least this.